# Trim part of string from column headers in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am working on a pandas dataframe  imported from a .csv file where there are about 18 columns. Each column has a item name and an image description in html format as column header. It is something like this:

```
A  <img width="300" alt="A" height="300".jpg">`  ` B <img width="400" alt="B" height="600".jpg"`......
```

and so on.

What I am trying to achieve is to get only the item name for my column headers and trim the image part. I tried this replace function:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('<img width="300" alt="A" height="300".jpg">', ''), inplace=True)
```

But it is not possible to give every column name as there are 30 similar files like this one and every image has a different description. I am looking for a more elegant solution here. I want my output to be something like:

```
A   B   C   D   ......so on
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\s*<.*>\s*$', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not familiar with regex, you could also try:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split(' ')[0], inplace=True)
```

given that there is always a space between your desired output and you undesired one.